# Can anyone point me to the Office2007Blue.xaml theme?

Tags: wpf, themes, ribbon, ribboncontrolslibrary

I would really like to include this in my application if anyone has any ideas.  Apparently it's not shipped with the ribbon anymore.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/RibbonControlsLibrary;component/Themes/Office2007Blue.xaml" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That file was included with an older preview of the ribbon library.  Since Microsoft no longer distributes the older versions, you would have to find one on the web.  Without too much trouble I found an older `RibbonControlsLibrary.DLL` included as part of an open source project.  To protect that project from liability, I'm not mentioning exactly where I found it.  The point is that that file contains `Office2007Blue.baml` in its resources that you could extract into XAML with a BAML decompiler.  The real problem I forsee is that you would need to find a license that permits you to extract it and to ship it with your application.

Comment: I noticed this issue myself. The "new" 4.0.x version that comes with the Visual Studio 2010 "WPF Ribbon window" template does not seem to contain these resources anymore. Using version 3.5.31016.1 did the trick. (I had fun finding this, because I have an existing project with the 3.5 and a new project, where it didn't work. Using the 3.5 dll solved this issue for me)